# iPhone - Working with Orientation and Multiple Views

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod-touch

I searched long and hard in an effort to figure this out. It took about 4-5 hours before I finally managed to reach a solution. I will be answering my own question in an effort to provide support to anyone who comes to the same problem.

So, I created the application Critical Mass Typer. It is a typing game that utilizes the keyboard as the main method of control. Words move towards the center of the screen where you have a nucleus. You type the word, and blow the word away before it reaches your nucleus. If 4 words make it to your nucleus, you reach critical mass, and explode (game over).

Now, I wanted to be able to support both landscape and portrait mode in the game. I thought about it ahead of time, and designed my classes such that it would be easy to implement. Setting up the game to do so was not a problem. Getting the views to rotate correctly was.

One thing that came up rather quickly was: any view that returns NO for the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method of a view controller will cancel out the returns of its subviews.

So, my main view controller (CriticalMassViewController) controls the launch/menu of the game, and adds, as a subview, a view controller that runs a game mode (CMGameViewController). I only want my main view controller to be in landscape mode because if I rotate it, the animation/buttons all run off the side. I would have to create another view or alter the position of everything on the screen if I wanted it to be set up for portrait mode. However, my game view needs to be able to switch. To accomplish this, you set the return value to the specific mode you want your main view to be. Then tell your game view to not return any mode. After that, register the game view for notifications, then handle the rotation on your own.

For Ex:
CriticalMassViewController.m:

```
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

CMGameViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    /*GUI setup code was here*/

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)nsn_notification {
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    /*Rotation Code
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        //Portrait setup
    } else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        //Landscape setup
    }

    */
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        // Return YES for supported orientations
        return NO; 
    }
```

Ok, so what's happening here? My main view controller only wants to be in LandscapeRight mode. So it stays like that since it never registers for any other orientation to auto rotate to. My game view controller needs to be able to rotate. If I use the following code for shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }
```

IT WILL NOT ROTATE WHEN THE IPHONE CHANGES ORIENTATION. This is because its super view says it doesn't want to rotate. Once the super view returns no, the subview doesn't even get asked. So instead, we the game view controller just says No, i dont want to autorotate to any view. Then we register for the notification of an orientation change, and call our own rotate method.

These last bits of code are how you handle the rotation yourself. Call rotateView from inside didRotate. Note, I only want the user to be able to rotate after a difficulty is chosen, so I have logic inside my didRotate method to determine if it should even rotate. The comments in the code will explain why the certain things are happening.

```
-(void) rotateView:(UIInterfaceOrientation)uiio_orientation {

    /*This line is very important if you are using the keyboard. This was actually the
    largest problem I had during this entire ordeal. If you switch orientations while
    the keyboard is already being displayed, it will stay in landscape orientation. To
    get it to switch to portrait, we have to tell the status bar that its orientation
    has changed. Once you do this, the keyboard switches to portrait*/
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = uiio_orientation;

    //Get the view you need to rotate
    UIView *portraitImageView = self.view;

    /*Check to make sure that you are in an orientation that you want to adjust to. If
    you don't check, you can make your view accidently rotate when the user orientates
    their phone to a position you aren't expecting*/
    if(uiio_orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || uiio_orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        if(uiio_orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
                    //This transform rotates the view 90 degrees counter clock wise.
            portraitImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
        } else if(uiio_orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
                    //This transform rotates the view back to its original position
            portraitImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
        }

        CGRect frame = portraitImageView.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.origin.x = 0;
        frame.size.width = portraitImageView.frame.size.height;
        frame.size.height = portraitImageView.frame.size.width;
        portraitImageView.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone, I know I had a very tough time with it, especially the keyboard going from landscape to portrait.

Comment: this comment is not related orientation but i was looking at your app like the font you used for the phrase "Let's do this!"  What font type is that?

Comment: Font is called "Blade 2" (i guess inspired by the movie).

Answer (score 2):

User written UIViewControllers are not meant to be nested on a single screen.    I believe the Apple line is "one UIViewController per screen."   Orientation change issues like this are one of the big reasons.    This is an understandable "mistake", one I'm tempted to make myself in some cases: the temptation is to use a UIViewController as a UIView loader in this case.  There's no real reason to use a UIViewController at all as a nested or reusable "widget" component in a screen, just to get to its view, you don't really get any benefit, because all of those useful handy functions like the orientation change, viewWillAppear, viewWillDisappear, will *not* be called automatically for you by any other UIViewController other than your own!   These calls are not "broadcast" but "forwarded" from UIViewController parent to UIViewController child.   And if you write your own UIViewController subclass, you're responsible for passing down any of these inherited method calls.

Your inner UIViewController was not "not called" because the outer UIViewController answered NO, it was not called because you did not forward the call to your nested UIViewController yourself.   The orientation change method `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, just like the other viewWill* methods, are not broadcast to all UIViewControllers, they are passed down the hierarchy from the top level window, from class to class.   Built-in UIViewControllers like UINavigationControllers and UITabBarControllers explicitly pass down these calls to their children, that's why it seems like a broadcast when they arrive but when you insert your own UINavigationController subclass to the VC hierarchy, you must yourself pass down these calls to any children UINavigationControllers.   This is what you must do if you want to write your own "global controller VC" like a UITabBarController replacement.

Comment: "one UIViewController per screen" is never mentioned in anything actually. What you are talking about is "One ViewController per View" saying that its a good idea to have a one to one relationship of view controllers and the views they control, which is just a common convention used by programmers. Beyond that, it's not a "rule" but rather a guideline to be used to make things "easier". Also, the view controller does pass the messages through to its children view controllers automatically. If you set all of the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation methods to return YES, they all rotate

Comment: You're saying with a hierarchy of .../customVC-A/customVC-B, that customVC-B will have its orientation methods called automatically WITHOUT having to forward them explicitly in VC-A?  That's not what I see, but then again I don't nest custom VCs all that much.

Comment: nope, Saying that With VC-A/VC-B, VC-A orientation methods will be called first, if it returns no, VC-B methods will not be called.

Comment: @ColdLogic: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW12 "You should not use multiple custom view controllers to manage different portions of the same view hierarchy."

Comment: @user102008: I don't... There are 3 separate views managed by different view controllers. "You should not use multiple custom view controllers to manage different portions of the same view hierarchy. Similarly, you should not use a single custom view controller object to manage multiple screens worth of content."

Comment: @ColdLogic: but they are on the same screen, so they are on the same hierarchy

Comment: @user102008: Ummmm, iDevices do not have multiple screens, so of course they are on the same screen. Via your logic, we shouldn't ever need more than 1 view controller

Comment: +1 for advising manual broadcast when using multiple VCs per screen - that is the key.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        {         
           //for portrait
             NSLog(@"portrait");
        }
        else if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
            // code for landscape orientation      

             NSLog(@"landscape");
        }
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your post, please include why/how your answer solves the problem.